# Ejecutar función al detectar el evento .change de alguno de los input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código jquery:

```
$("#Inmuebles_PrecioPropietario").change(function () { addsuma(); });
$("#Inmuebles_Honorarios").change(function () { addsuma(); });
$('#Inmuebles_Porcentaje').change(function () { addsuma(); });
$('#Inmuebles_IdIva').change(function () { addsuma(); });
```

Pero quiero resumirlo... cuando alguno de los input cambie ejecute la funcion, algo asi pero no me funciona:

```
($("#Inmuebles_PrecioPropietario")||$("#Inmuebles_Honorarios")||$('#Inmuebles_Porcentaje')|| $('#Inmuebles_IdIva')).change(function () { addsuma(); });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplemente ingresá separados por coma todos los elementos:

```
$("#Inmuebles_PrecioPropietario, #Inmuebles_Honorarios, #Inmuebles_Porcentaje, #Inmuebles_IdIva").change(function () {
  addsuma();
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Además de lo indicado por @ricardo-ruiz-benites, tienes la opción de seleccionar elementos que empiezan por un valor concreto con un selector de atributo (en tu caso por `id`). Veo que todos tus ids empiezar por "Inmuebles_" por lo que podrías seleccionarlos todos a la vez así:

```js
$("input[id^='Inmuebles_']" ).change(function(){
console.log("Este es mi input: " + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Inmuebles_PrecioPropietario">
<input id="Inmuebles_Honorarios">
<input id="Inmuebles_Porcentaje">
<input id="Inmuebles_IdIva">
```

Más [info](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) sobre el selector de atributo.

Y más [info](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) sobre los selectores en `jQuery`